# MIPS:representing a mips assembly in machine code

Tags: assembly, mips

BSD

[nextCH is 0x400100]

```
nextCh: lb $t0,-3($t2)
        beq $t0,$zero,strEnd
        add $t9,$t9,$t0
        addi $t2,$t2,-12
        j nextCh
strEnd:
```

I can't figure out what to do with `strEnd`. How can I represent it in decimal?

Comment: _"cant figure out what to do with strEnd"_ You know the address of `nextCh`; you know the number of instructions between `nextCh` and `strEnd`; and you know the size of each instruction (4 bytes). So determining the address of `strEnd` is trivial.

Comment: represent what in decimal?

Comment: So I can assume that strEnd is nextCh + 2*4bytes?

Comment: Improved Formatting and Removed Unnecessary Sentences